# Objects seperating in 3d print

Tags: 3d-printing

I have created an object in blender, copied it, mirrored it and put them together to create one object.

The random thing is that when 3D printing the Stl file, it's seperating the 'original' half into its initial sections (objects) it was created from. Yet the copied half prints fine.

Totally confused, and help is appreciated.

[image: printing correctly]

[image: split sections]

Comment: Could it be that you have to merge nodes to make a single object of all the "initial sections"? Joining two objects does not merge vertices, edges and faces.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend through Blender Exchange?